# How to remove Tracker points from green screen footage

Tags: video, after-effects, greenscreen, visual-effects

I have downloaded **green screen** footage that has tracker points with it. I have easily remove the green screen but I am unable to remove tracker points from it.

I have google it, but unable to find any way to remove tracker points from video.

I am using *Adobe After effects CC*. Kindly guide me or refer me some good tutorial on how to remove tracker points from a video:

[image]

Comment: Really? Why do you want to remove the markers in this case?

Comment: They are appearing over my video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use greenscreen. You need to track markers, and put your footage above the markers and greenscren. Just lock position on markers points.

Like in this video, but track not corners, but markers.

Then you can add some effects for footage, to look more immersive.

Comment: You are welcome! Have a good luck!